# How to solve "undeclared identifier" error?

Tags: c++

I'm working on my college assignment about a simple C++ program. So far I've met most of the question requirements, yet I'm stuck at the **undeclared identifier** error at the moment. The error mentioned can be found at the commented section of the code, where the comments include the term "problematic part". My question is, how to solve the **undeclared identifier** error?

I'll be grateful if you could try compiling the source code and pinpoint the problem.

Build error:

```
1>c:\users\adrian khor\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ict1101_as1_4\ict1101_as1_4\ict1101_as1_4.cpp(74): error C2065: 'feeReportTotalAfterDiscountedFee' : undeclared identifier
```

(MS Visual Studio Pro 2013)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int qtyVehicleCar, qtyVehicleTaxi, qtyVehicleTruck;

    /* Text UI component */
    cout << "=====================================\n";
    cout << "=====================================\n";
    cout << "====== Malaysia Highway Company =====\n";
    cout << "=====================================\n";
    cout << "=====================================\n";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter quantity of the vehicles on 1st January 2014: " << endl;
    cout << "Car\t\t:\t";
    cin >> qtyVehicleCar;

    cout << "Taxi\t\t:\t";
    cin >> qtyVehicleTaxi;

    cout << "Truck\t\t:\t";
    cin >> qtyVehicleTruck;

    /* Lay out the Report table */
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    cout << "Report\n";
    cout << "--------\n";
    cout << endl;

    /* Processes */

    /* ============ */
    /* Declaration */
    /* ============ */
    // Report Items
    double feeOriginalCar, feeOriginalTaxi, feeOriginalTruck;
    feeOriginalCar = 2.00;
    feeOriginalTaxi = 1.00;
    feeOriginalTruck = 3.50;

    double feeTotalOriginalCar, feeTotalOriginalTaxi, feeTotalOriginalTruck;
    feeTotalOriginalCar = qtyVehicleCar * feeOriginalCar;
    feeTotalOriginalTaxi = qtyVehicleTaxi * feeOriginalTaxi;
    feeTotalOriginalTruck = qtyVehicleTruck * feeOriginalTruck;

    double rateDiscountCar, rateDiscountTaxi, rateDiscountTruck;
    rateDiscountCar = 2;
    rateDiscountTaxi = 10;
    rateDiscountTruck = 15;

    double feeTotalDiscountedCar, feeTotalDiscountedTaxi, feeTotalDiscountedTruck;
    feeTotalDiscountedCar = (rateDiscountCar / 100) * feeTotalOriginalCar;
    feeTotalDiscountedTaxi = (rateDiscountTaxi / 100) * feeTotalOriginalTaxi;
    feeTotalDiscountedTruck = (rateDiscountTruck / 100) * feeTotalOriginalTruck;

    double feeTotalAfterDiscountedCar, feeTotalAfterDiscountedTaxi, feeTotalAfterDiscountedTruck;
    feeTotalAfterDiscountedCar = feeTotalOriginalCar - feeTotalDiscountedCar;
    feeTotalAfterDiscountedTaxi = feeTotalOriginalTaxi - feeTotalDiscountedTaxi;
    feeTotalAfterDiscountedTruck = feeTotalOriginalTruck - feeTotalDiscountedTruck;

    // Final Output
    double feeReportTotalOriginalFee, feeReportTotalDiscountedFee, feeReportTotalAfterDiscounted;

    feeReportTotalOriginalFee = feeTotalOriginalCar + feeTotalOriginalTaxi + feeTotalOriginalTruck;
    feeReportTotalDiscountedFee = feeTotalDiscountedCar + feeTotalDiscountedTaxi + feeTotalDiscountedTruck;

    /* The problematic part #2*/
    /* feeReportTotalAfterDiscountedFee = feeReportTotalOriginalFee - feeReportTotalAfterDiscountedFee; */ /* OR */
     feeReportTotalAfterDiscountedFee = (feeTotalOriginalCar - feeTotalDiscountedCar) + (feeTotalOriginalTaxi - feeTotalDiscountedTaxi) + (feeTotalOriginalTruck - feeTotalDiscountedTruck); 

    cout << "Item\t\t\t\t" << "Car\t" << "Taxi\t" << "Truck\t" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Original fee\t\t\t" << "RM " << feeOriginalCar << "\t" << "RM " << feeOriginalTaxi << "\t" << "RM " << feeOriginalTruck << endl;
    cout << "Quantity\t\t\t" << qtyVehicleCar << "\t" << qtyVehicleTaxi << "\t" << qtyVehicleTruck << endl;
    cout << "Total original fee\t\t" << "RM " << feeTotalOriginalCar << "\t" << "RM " << feeTotalOriginalTaxi << "\t" << "RM " << feeTotalOriginalTruck << endl;
    cout << "Discount rate\t\t\t" << rateDiscountCar << "%\t" << rateDiscountTaxi << "%\t" << rateDiscountTruck << "%\t" << endl;
    cout << "Total discounted fee\t\t" << "RM " << feeTotalDiscountedCar << "\t" << "RM " << feeTotalDiscountedTaxi << "\t" << "RM " << feeTotalDiscountedTruck << endl;
    cout << "Total after discounted fee\t" << "RM " << feeTotalAfterDiscountedCar << "\t" << "RM " << feeTotalAfterDiscountedTaxi << "\t" << "RM " << feeTotalAfterDiscountedTruck << endl;
    cout << endl;

    /* Displays output */
    cout << "Total original fee\t\t:\t" << "RM " << feeReportTotalOriginalFee << endl;
    cout << "Total discounted fee\t\t:\t" << "RM " << feeReportTotalDiscountedFee << endl;
    cout << "Total after discounted fee\t:\t" << "RM " << feeReportTotalAfterDiscountedFee << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;

    /* Displays end line */
    cout << "------------------- End of Program -------------------" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You just need to declare it like you declare all the other variables.

Comment: The compiler is telling you EXACTLY what is wrong. Where have you declared `feeReportTotalAfterDiscountedFee`? You just start using it without telling the program whether it is an `int` a `float` or something else.  Suggest you delete the question since it's really just a typo.

Comment: You have `feeReportTotalDiscountedFee` and `feeReportTotalAfterDiscounted but **no** `feeReportTotalAfterDiscountedFee`. You should declare feeReportTotalAfterDiscountedFee.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I did declare it, but for the purpose of asking questions, I commented out that section. (Actually I coded two solutions; neither worked for me)

Comment: **Declaring** a variable entails **declaring** why type it is. Always.

Comment: No, you didn't. You tried to assign to it but you never declared it.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I "tried" but I actually didn't declared it. Thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear you gave `feeReportTotalAfterDiscountedFee` a type. The first occurrence of it seems to be within the comments, which don't provide any indication as to *what* it actually is. Given the types of the other variables in your code I'm assuming it's a `double`, but the compiler doesn't know that.

Try putting `double` in front of the `feeReportTotalAfterDiscountedFee` on the first commented line (of course after uncommenting them).

Comment: Not me, but in general answers to questions that ought to be closed are discouraged ("help vampirism").

Comment: @AndrewMedico that doesn't necessarily warrant a downvote. Flag to vote-close the question instead. My answer is perfectly valid and relevant.

Comment: I'm just saying, people on Meta.SO have said they do that.

Comment: Thanks, Qix. Your answer actually hit me in the head as I used IntelliSense blindly without looking at the variables (long name actually). The program now works flawlessly. Thank you again! :)

Comment: @AndrewMedico Oh I'm aware. Don't necessarily agree with it but you can vote how you please.

Comment: @Qix An answer can be correct without neccessarily being good. Each answer to a bad question encourages the OP to ask more bad questions. Why would he bother asking good questions if he gets his answer anyway ? There's no consensus on that though.

Comment: @Keats because the question is flagged and on hold, telling him *exactly* why his question isn't good. The answers are irrelevant at that point.

Comment: @Qix Just cared to comment :)